# Java Spring Boot Config Standard

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have an interface hierarchy like this:

```
public interface Shape {
    //code
}

@Component
public class Circle implements Shape {
    //code
}

@Component
public class Square implements Shape {
    //code
}
```

I want to know the best way to wire these in using Spring Boot bean convention.

**Solution 1:**

```
@Component(value = "Circle")
public class Circle implements Shape {
    //code
}

@Component(value = "Square")
public class Square implements Shape {
    //code
}

@Configuration
public class ShapeConfig {
    @Bean
    Foo circleFoo(@Qualifiers("Circle") Shape shape) {
        return new Foo(shape);
    }

    @Bean
    Foo squareFoo(@Qualifiers("Square") Shape shape) {
        return new Foo(shape);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
@Component
public class Circle implements Shape {
    //code
}

@Component
public class Square implements Shape {
    //code
}

@Configuration
public class ShapeConfig {
    @Bean
    Foo circleFoo(Circle shape) {
        return new Foo(shape);
    }

    @Bean
    Foo squareFoo(Square shape) {
        return new Foo(shape);
    }
}
```

What's the best java/spring practice in this case? I find the value and @Qualifier stuff to be a bit verbose but I'm wondering if wiring in concrete implementations is frowned upon

Comment: Interesting question... I don't have a definitive answer, but for that case I'd go for Solution 2. I tend to prefer avoiding magic annotations when I can. You don't gain anything with the qualifier, it seems pointless to delegate to spring something so trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your implementation of application

In case of autowire, spring firstly tries to autowire been byName then if not found it go for by type and then by constructor(if by type not found any bean).

Until we don't have multiple beans with the same type and different name we are good with solution 2(we can use autowire byName also instead of by constructor ), but in case of if we have 2 or more then 2 beans with the same type then we go for solution 1(Qualifier)
    eg:

```
 @Configuration
    public class Config {
    @Bean(name = "circle1")
    public Circle getCircle1(){
        Circle c = new Circle();
        c.setRadius(1.5);
        return c;
    }

    @Bean(name = "circle2")
    public Circle getCircle2(){
        Circle c = new Circle();
        c.setRadius(10);
        return c;
    }
    }
```

suppose i have a service

```
@Component
CirculeService {
@Autowire  @Qualifier("circle1") Circle circle1
@Autowire @Qualifier("circle2")  Circle circle2
}
```

here above exapme i have autowire with help of Qualifier (same for autowire by constructor)